# PHP - Difference between 2 dates, returning 0

Tags: php

```
$from_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time = $row['clock'];

echo  $from_time - $to_time;
```

The $to_time is a time stamp in the MySQL database. $row['clock'] = 2013-10-27 13:28:01.

When I run this code, the echo always returns 0.

I am trying to get the amount of seconds between the dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're basically trying to subtract two strings. If you echo `$from_time`, you can find out that the value will be something like `2013-10-27 12:49:270`, and `$to_time` will be another string -- `2013-10-27 13:28:01`.

You need to convert them into timestamps before doing the substraction:

```
$from_time = time();
$to_time = strtotime($row['clock']);
```

I recommend using the `DateTime` class for working with dates and times.

This is how you find the difference between two dates using `DateTime` class:

```
$from_time = new DateTime('now');
$to_time = new DateTime("2013-10-27 13:28:01");
$interval = $from_time->diff($to_time);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes %S seconds');
```

Output:

```
0 hours 31 minutes 48 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

first convert `$to_time` to `timestamp` using `strtotime()` and then subtract,only then you will get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` will convert a date to UNIX a timestamp,
which is in seconds and will enable you to do your calculation.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

```
$from_time = time();
$to_time = strtotime($row['clock']);

echo  $from_time - $to_time;
```

Comment: You don't need to do `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` -- just `time()` is enough.